# What kind of blurs can be implemented in pixel shaders?

Tags: glsl, shader, gpu, hlsl, pixel-shader

Gaussian, box, radial, directional, motion blur, zoom blur, etc.

I read that Gaussian blur can be broken down in passes that could be implemented in pixel shaders, but couldn't find any samples.

Is it right to assume that any effect that concerns itself with pixels other than itself, can't be implemented in pixel shaders?

Answer (score 6):

You can implement everything, as long you are able to pass information to the shader.

The trick, in this cases, is to perform a multiple pass rendering. The final shader will take a certain number of samplers, that are the non-blurred sources, which are used to compute blurred values.

For example, using multiple textures is possible to emulate effects based on the accumulation buffer.

---

to implement a gaussian blur, render the scene onto a frambuffer object, with attached a texture on the color attachment. This is the first pass.

As second pass, render a textured quad, where the texture is the one generated in the first step. Textures coordinates are passed from vertex stage to fragment stage, interpolated across the quad. Indeed you have texture coordinate for each fragment; apply a offset for each coordinate to fetch textels around the underlying one, and perform the gaussian blur.

Comment: Thanks, what kind of inputs can I pass for these blurs? I thought I only get a pixel and its colors, etc, not its coordinates, or anything else. Also do you know how I could implement a Gaussian or box blur as a pixel shader?

Answer (score 5):

general 'pipeline' for postprocessing effects

```
setRenderTarget(myRenderTarget); // or FBO in GL
drawAwsomeScene();

setdefaultRenderTarget();   // draw to screen...

blurShader.use();
// shader needs to know what is the size of one pixel on the screen
blurShader.uniform2f("texelSize", 1/screenW, 1/screenH);

// set the texture with scene rendered...
setRenderTargetTexture();

drawFullScreenQuad();

// other effects...
```

useful examples/tutorial for blur: http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a generic convolution fragment shader (pixel shader)

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texUnit;
uniform float[9] conMatrix;
uniform float conWeight;
uniform vec2 conPixel;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0);
    vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
    vec2 offset = conPixel * 1.5;
    vec2 start = texCoord - offset;
    vec2 current = start;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        color += texture2D( texUnit, current ) * conMatrix[i]; 

        current.x += conPixel.x;
        if (i == 2 || i == 5) {
            current.x = start.x;
            current.y += conPixel.y; 
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = color * conWeight;
}
```

For a Blur:

```
where conPixel is {1/screen width, 1/screen height}
where conMatrix is {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
where conWeight is 1.0 / 9.0
where texUnit is 0
```

Answer (score 2):

An often seen implementation to achieve a blur effect of a scene is the [Gaussian blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur), implemented by a 2 pass post-processing.
This is an approximation which first blurs along the X-Axis in the 1st pass and along the Y-Axis in the 2nd pass (or vice versa). This results in a better performance for strong blurring.
The blur shader uses a [normal (or Gaussian) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). For the 2 passes is used the same shader program, with individual direction settings for the 2 passes, stored in the uniform `vec2 u_dir`. The strength of the blur effect can be varied with the uniform variable `float u_sigma` in the range [0.0, 1.0].
The scene is written to frame buffer with a texture bound to the color plane. A screen space pass uses the texture as the input to blur the output along the X-axis. The X-axis blur pass writes to another frame buffer, with a texture bound to its color plane. This texture is used as the input, for the final blur process along the Y-axis.
A detailed description of the blur algorithm can be found at the answer to the question [OpenGL es 2.0 Gaussian blur on triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779142/opengl-es-2-0-gaussian-blur-on-triangle) or [LeranOpenGL - Gaussian blur](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Bloom).

*Blur* Vertex shader

```c
#version 330

in  vec2 inPos;
out vec2 pos;

void main()
{
    pos = inPos;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

*Blur* Fragment shader

```c
#version 330

in vec2 pos;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2      u_textureSize;
uniform float     u_sigma;
uniform vec2      u_dir;

float CalcGauss( float x, float sigma )
{
    if ( sigma <= 0.0 )
        return 0.0;
  return exp( -(x*x) / (2.0 * sigma) ) / (2.0 * 3.14157 * sigma);
}

void main()
{
    vec2 texC     = pos.st * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec4 texCol   = texture2D( u_texture, texC );
    vec4 gaussCol = vec4( texCol.rgb, 1.0 );
    vec2 step     = u_dir / u_textureSize;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 32; ++ i )
    {
        float weight = CalcGauss( float(i) / 32.0, u_sigma * 0.5 );
        if ( weight < 1.0/255.0 )
            break;
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC + step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC - step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
    }
    gaussCol.rgb = clamp( gaussCol.rgb / gaussCol.w, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( gaussCol.rgb, 1.0 );
}
```

See also the answers to the following question:

- [Fast Gaussian blur at pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745199/fast-gaussian-blur-at-pause)
- [OpenGL es 2.0 Gaussian blur on triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779142/opengl-es-2-0-gaussian-blur-on-triangle)
- [How to get a "Glow" shader effect in OpenGL ES 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166384/how-to-get-a-glow-shader-effect-in-opengl-es-2-0)

See a WebGL example:

```js
var readInput = true;
function changeEventHandler(event){
readInput = true;
}

(function loadscene() {

var resize, gl, progDraw, progBlur, vp_size, blurFB;
var canvas;
var camera;
var bufCube = {};
var bufQuad = {};
var shininess = 10.0;
var glow = 10.0;
var sigma = 0.8;
var radius = 1.0;

function render(deltaMS){

    if ( readInput ) {
        //readInput = false;
        var sliderScale = 100;
        sigma     = document.getElementById( "sigma" ).value / sliderScale;
        radius    = document.getElementById( "radius" ).value / sliderScale;
    }

    vp_size = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    camera.Update( vp_size );
        
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    // set up framebuffer
    gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, blurFB[0] );
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, blurFB[0].width, blurFB[0].height );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    // setup view projection and model
    var prjMat = camera.Perspective();
    var viewMat = camera.Orbit();
    var modelMat = IdentM44();
    modelMat = camera.AutoModelMatrix();
    
    // set up draw shader
    ShProg.Use( progDraw.prog );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw.prog, "u_projectionMat44", prjMat );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw.prog, "u_modelViewMat44", Multiply(viewMat, modelMat) );
    ShProg.SetF1( progDraw.prog, "u_shininess", shininess );
    
    // draw scene
    VertexBuffer.Draw( bufCube );

    // set blur-X framebuffer and bind frambuffer texture
    gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, blurFB[1] );
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, blurFB[1].width, blurFB[1].height );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    var texUnit = 1;
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, blurFB[0].color0_texture );

    // set up blur-X shader
    ShProg.Use( progBlur.prog );
    ShProg.SetI1( progBlur.prog, "u_texture", texUnit )
    ShProg.SetF2( progBlur.prog, "u_textureSize", vp_size );
    ShProg.SetF1( progBlur.prog, "u_sigma", sigma )
    ShProg.SetF1( progBlur.prog, "u_radius", radius )
    ShProg.SetF2( progBlur.prog, "u_dir", [1.0, 0.0] )

    // draw full screen space
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progBlur.inPos );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufQuad.pos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progBlur.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufQuad.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( progBlur.inPos );

    // reset framebuffer and bind frambuffer texture
    gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null );
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, vp_size[0], vp_size[1] );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    texUnit = 2;
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, blurFB[1].color0_texture );

    // set up pst process shader
    ShProg.SetI1( progBlur.prog, "u_texture", texUnit )
    ShProg.SetF1( progBlur.prog, "u_radius", radius )
    ShProg.SetF2( progBlur.prog, "u_dir", [0.0, 1.0] )

    // draw full screen space
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progBlur.inPos );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufQuad.pos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progBlur.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufQuad.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( progBlur.inPos );

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
        return null;

    progDraw = {}
    progDraw.prog = ShProg.Create( 
    [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
    ] );
    if ( !progDraw.prog )
        return null;
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.prog, "inPos" );
    progDraw.inNV  = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.prog, "inNV" );
    progDraw.inCol = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.prog, "inCol" );

    progBlur = {}
    progBlur.prog = ShProg.Create( 
    [ { source : "post-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "blur-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
    ] );
    progBlur.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progBlur.prog, "inPos" );
    if ( !progBlur.prog )
        return;    
    
    // create cube
    var cubePos = [
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0 ];
    var cubeCol = [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ];
    var cubeHlpInx = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 3, 7, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 0, 4, 5 ];  
    var cubePosData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; ++ i ) {
    cubePosData.push( cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+1], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+2] );
    }
    var cubeNVData = [];
    for ( var i1 = 0; i1 < cubeHlpInx.length; i1 += 4 ) {
    var nv = [0, 0, 0];
    for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 ) {
        var i = i1 + i2;
        nv[0] += cubePosData[i*3]; nv[1] += cubePosData[i*3+1]; nv[2] += cubePosData[i*3+2];
    }
    for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 )
    cubeNVData.push( nv[0], nv[1], nv[2] );
    }
    var cubeColData = [];
    for ( var is = 0; is < 6; ++ is ) {
    for ( var ip = 0; ip < 4; ++ ip ) {
        cubeColData.push( cubeCol[is*3], cubeCol[is*3+1], cubeCol[is*3+2] ); 
    }
    }
    var cubeInxData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; i += 4 ) {
    cubeInxData.push( i, i+1, i+2, i, i+2, i+3 );   
    }
    bufCube = VertexBuffer.Create(
    [ { data : cubePosData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos },
    { data : cubeNVData,  attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inNV },
    { data : cubeColData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inCol } ],
    cubeInxData );

    bufQuad.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufQuad.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( [ -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0 ] ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufQuad.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufQuad.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ] ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );  
    
    camera = new Camera( [0, 3, 0.0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], 90, vp_size, 0.5, 100 );

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
    //vp_size = [256, 256]
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];

    var fbsize = Math.max(vp_size[0], vp_size[1]);
    fbsize = 1 << 31 - Math.clz32(fbsize); // nearest power of 2

    blurFB = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 2; ++ i ) {
        fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
        fb.width = fbsize;
        fb.height = fbsize;
        gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb );
        fb.color0_texture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, fb.color0_texture );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );
        gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, fb.width, fb.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null );
        fb.renderbuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
        gl.bindRenderbuffer( gl.RENDERBUFFER, fb.renderbuffer );
        gl.renderbufferStorage( gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, fb.width, fb.height );
        gl.framebufferTexture2D( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, fb.color0_texture, 0 );
        gl.framebufferRenderbuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, fb.renderbuffer );
        gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, null );
        gl.bindRenderbuffer( gl.RENDERBUFFER, null );
        gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null );
        blurFB.push( fb );
    }
}

function Fract( val ) { 
    return val - Math.trunc( val );
}
function CalcAng( deltaTime, intervall ) {
    return Fract( deltaTime / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}
function CalcMove( deltaTime, intervall, range ) {
    var pos = self.Fract( deltaTime / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0
    var pos = pos < 1.0 ? pos : (2.0-pos)
    return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * pos;
}    
function EllipticalPosition( a, b, angRag ) {
    var a_b = a * a - b * b
    var ea = (a_b <= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( a_b );
    var eb = (a_b >= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( -a_b );
    return [ a * Math.sin( angRag ) - ea, b * Math.cos( angRag ) - eb, 0 ];
}

function IdentM44() {
    return [ 1, 0, 0, 0,    0, 1, 0, 0,    0, 0, 1, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1 ];
};

function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
    var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
    var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
    var matB = matA.slice(0);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
        matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
        matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
    }
    return matB;
}

function Rotate(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var s = Math.sin(angRad), c = Math.cos(angRad);
    var x = axis[0], y = axis[1], z = axis[2]; 
    matB = [
        x*x*(1-c)+c,   x*y*(1-c)-z*s, x*z*(1-c)+y*s, 0,
        y*x*(1-c)+z*s, y*y*(1-c)+c,   y*z*(1-c)-x*s, 0,
        z*x*(1-c)-y*s, z*y*(1-c)+x*s, z*z*(1-c)+c,   0,
        0,             0,             0,             1 ];
    return Multiply(matA, matB);
}    

function Multiply(matA, matB) {
    matC = IdentM44();
    for (var i0=0; i0<4; ++i0 )
        for (var i1=0; i1<4; ++i1 )
            matC[i0*4+i1] = matB[i0*4+0] * matA[0*4+i1] + matB[i0*4+1] * matA[1*4+i1] + matB[i0*4+2] * matA[2*4+i1] + matB[i0*4+3] * matA[3*4+i1]  
    return matC;
}

function Cross( a, b ) { return [ a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0], 0.0 ]; }
function Dot( a, b ) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }
function Normalize( v ) {
    var len = Math.sqrt( v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] );
    return [ v[0] / len, v[1] / len, v[2] / len ];
}

Camera = function( pos, target, up, fov_y, vp, near, far ) {
this.Time = function() { return Date.now(); }
this.pos = pos;
this.target = target;
this.up = up;
this.fov_y = fov_y;
this.vp = vp;
this.near = near;
this.far = far;
this.orbit_mat = this.current_orbit_mat = this.model_mat = this.current_model_mat = IdentM44();
this.mouse_drag = this.auto_spin = false;
this.auto_rotate = true;
this.mouse_start = [0, 0];
this.mouse_drag_axis = [0, 0, 0];
this.mouse_drag_angle = 0;
this.mouse_drag_time = 0;
this.drag_start_T = this.rotate_start_T = this.Time();
this.Ortho = function() {
    var fn = this.far + this.near;
    var f_n = this.far - this.near;
    var w = this.vp[0];
    var h = this.vp[1];
    return [
        2/w, 0,   0,       0,
        0,   2/h, 0,       0,
        0,   0,   -2/f_n,  0,
        0,   0,   -fn/f_n, 1 ];
};  
this.Perspective = function() {
    var n = this.near;
    var f = this.far;
    var fn = f + n;
    var f_n = f - n;
    var r = this.vp[0] / this.vp[1];
    var t = 1 / Math.tan( Math.PI * this.fov_y / 360 );
    return [
        t/r, 0, 0,          0,
        0,   t, 0,          0,
        0,   0, -fn/f_n,   -1,
        0,   0, -2*f*n/f_n, 0 ];
}; 
this.LookAt = function() {
    var mz = Normalize( [ this.pos[0]-this.target[0], this.pos[1]-this.target[1], this.pos[2]-this.target[2] ] );
    var mx = Normalize( Cross( this.up, mz ) );
    var my = Normalize( Cross( mz, mx ) );
    var tx = Dot( mx, this.pos );
    var ty = Dot( my, this.pos );
    var tz = Dot( [-mz[0], -mz[1], -mz[2]], this.pos ); 
    return [mx[0], my[0], mz[0], 0, mx[1], my[1], mz[1], 0, mx[2], my[2], mz[2], 0, tx, ty, tz, 1]; 
};
this.Orbit = function() {
    return Multiply(this.LookAt(), this.OrbitMatrix());
}; 
this.OrbitMatrix = function() {
    return (this.mouse_drag || (this.auto_rotate && this.auto_spin)) ? Multiply(this.current_orbit_mat, this.orbit_mat) : this.orbit_mat;
};
this.AutoModelMatrix = function() {
    return this.auto_rotate ? Multiply(this.current_model_mat, this.model_mat) : this.model_mat;
};
this.Update = function(vp_size) {
    if (vp_size)
        this.vp = vp_size;
    var current_T = this.Time();
    this.current_model_mat = IdentM44()
    if (this.mouse_drag) {
        this.current_orbit_mat = Rotate(IdentM44(), this.mouse_drag_angle, this.mouse_drag_axis);
    } else if (this.auto_rotate) {
        if (this.auto_spin ) {
            if (this.mouse_drag_time > 0 ) {
                var angle = this.mouse_drag_angle * (current_T - this.rotate_start_T) / this.mouse_drag_time;
                this.current_orbit_mat = Rotate(IdentM44(), angle, this.mouse_drag_axis);
            }
        } else {
            var auto_angle_x = Fract( (current_T - this.rotate_start_T) / 13000.0 ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            var auto_angle_y = Fract( (current_T - this.rotate_start_T) / 17000.0 ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            this.current_model_mat = RotateAxis( this.current_model_mat, auto_angle_x, 0 );
            this.current_model_mat = RotateAxis( this.current_model_mat, auto_angle_y, 1 );
        }
    }
};
this.ChangeMotionMode = function(drag, spin, auto ) {
    var new_drag = drag;
    var new_auto = new_drag ? false : auto;
    var new_spin = new_auto ? spin : false;
    change = this.mouse_drag != new_drag || this.auto_rotate != new_auto || this.auto_spin != new_spin; 
    if (!change)
        return;
    if (new_drag && !this.mouse_drag) {
        this.drag_start_T = this.Time();
        this.mouse_drag_angle = 0.0;
        this.mouse_drag_time = 0;
    }
    if (new_auto && !this.auto_rotate)
        this.rotate_start_T = this.Time();
    this.mouse_drag = new_drag; 
    this.auto_rotate = new_auto;  
    this.auto_spin = new_spin;
    this.orbit_mat = Multiply(this.current_orbit_mat, this.orbit_mat);
    this.current_orbit_mat = IdentM44();
    this.model_mat = Multiply(this.current_model_mat, this.model_mat);
    this.current_model_mat = IdentM44();
};
this.OnMouseDown = function( event ) {
    var rect = gl.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    if ( event.clientX < rect.left || event.clientX > rect.right ) return;
    if ( event.clientY < rect.top || event.clientY > rect.bottom ) return;
    if (event.button == 0) { // left button
        this.mouse_start = [event.clientX, event.clientY]; 
        this.ChangeMotionMode( true, false, false );
    }
};
this.OnMouseUp = function( event ) {
    if (event.button == 0) { // left button
        this.ChangeMotionMode( false, true, true );
    } else if (event.button == 1) {// middle button
        this.ChangeMotionMode( false, false, !this.auto_rotate );
    }
};
this.OnMouseMove = function( event ) {
    var dx = (event.clientX-this.mouse_start[0]) / this.vp[0];
    var dy = (event.clientY-this.mouse_start[1]) / this.vp[1];
    var len = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    if (this.mouse_drag && len > 0) {
        this.mouse_drag_angle = Math.PI*len;
        this.mouse_drag_axis = [dy/len, 0, -dx/len];
        this.mouse_drag_time = this.Time() - this.drag_start_T;
    }
};

this.domElement = document;
var cam = this;
//this.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', function(e) { event.preventDefault(); }, false );
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(e) { cam.OnMouseDown(e) }, false );
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function(e) { cam.OnMouseUp(e) }, false );
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function(e) { cam.OnMouseMove(e) }, false );
//this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', hid_events.onMouseWheel, false );
//this.domElement.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', hid_events.onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox
}

var ShProg = {};
ShProg.Create = function( shaderList ) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
        var shderObj = this.Compile( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
        if ( shderObj == 0 )
            return 0;
        shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
    }
    var progObj = this.Link( shaderObjs )
    if ( progObj != 0 ) {
        progObj.attrInx = {};
        var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveAttrib( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.attrInx[name] = gl.getAttribLocation( progObj, name );
        }
        progObj.uniLoc = {};
        var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveUniform( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.uniLoc[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( progObj, name );
        }
    }
    return progObj;
}
ShProg.AttrI = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.attrInx[name]; } 
ShProg.UniformL = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.uniLoc[name]; } 
ShProg.Use = function( progObj ) { gl.useProgram( progObj ); } 
ShProg.SetI1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1i( progObj.uniLoc[name], val ); }
ShProg.SetF1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1f( progObj.uniLoc[name], val ); }
ShProg.SetF2  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform2fv( progObj.uniLoc[name], arr ); }
ShProg.SetF3  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform3fv( progObj.uniLoc[name], arr ); }
ShProg.SetF4  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform4fv( progObj.uniLoc[name], arr ); }
ShProg.SetM33 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv( progObj.uniLoc[name], false, mat ); }
ShProg.SetM44 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv( progObj.uniLoc[name], false, mat ); }
ShProg.Compile = function( source, shaderStage ) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript)
    source = shaderScript.text;
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
    gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
    gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : null;
} 
ShProg.Link = function( shaderObjs ) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
        gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
    gl.linkProgram( prog );
    status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    gl.useProgram( null );
    return status ? prog : null;
}

var VertexBuffer = {
Create: function(attribs, indices) {
    var buffer = { buf: [], attr: [], inx: gl.createBuffer(), inxLen: indices.length };
    for (var i=0; i<attribs.length; ++i) {
        buffer.buf.push(gl.createBuffer());
        buffer.attr.push({ size : attribs[i].attrSize, loc : attribs[i].attrLoc });
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attribs[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    return buffer;
},
Draw: function(bufObj) {
    for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i) {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i]);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc);
    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx);
    gl.drawElements(bufObj.primitve_type ? bufObj.primitve_type : gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i)
       gl.disableVertexAttribArray(bufObj.attr[i].loc);
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
} };

initScene();

})();
```

```css
html,body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#gui { position : absolute; top : 0; left : 0; }
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 inPos;
attribute vec3 inNV;
attribute vec3 inCol;

varying vec3 vertPos;
varying vec3 vertNV;
varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform mat4 u_projectionMat44;
uniform mat4 u_modelViewMat44;

void main()
{
    vertNV      = mat3( u_modelViewMat44 ) * normalize( inNV );
    vertCol     = inCol;
    vec4 pos    = u_modelViewMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
    vertPos     = pos.xyz / pos.w;
    gl_Position = u_projectionMat44 * pos;
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vertPos;
varying vec3 vertNV;
varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform float u_shininess;

void main()
{
    vec3 color = vertCol;
    vec3  normalV  = normalize( vertNV );
    vec3  eyeV     = normalize( -vertPos );
    vec3  halfV    = normalize( eyeV + normalV );
    float NdotH    = max( 0.0, dot( normalV, halfV ) );
    float shineFac = ( u_shininess + 2.0 ) * pow( NdotH, u_shininess ) / ( 2.0 * 3.14159265 );
    gl_FragColor   = vec4( color.rgb * (0.2 + NdotH), 1.0 );
} 
</script>

<script id="post-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;

varying   vec2 pos;

void main()
{
    pos = inPos;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="blur-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 pos;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2      u_textureSize;
uniform float     u_sigma;
uniform float     u_radius;
uniform vec2      u_dir;

float CalcGauss( float x, float sigma )
{
    if ( sigma <= 0.0 )
        return 0.0;
  return exp( -(x*x) / (2.0 * sigma) ) / (2.0 * 3.14157 * sigma);
}

void main()
{
    vec2 texC     = pos.st * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec4 texCol   = texture2D( u_texture, texC );
    vec4 gaussCol = vec4( texCol.rgb, 1.0 );
    vec2 step     = u_dir / u_textureSize;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 32; ++ i )
    {
        float weight = CalcGauss( float(i) / 32.0, u_sigma * 0.5 );
        if ( weight < 1.0/255.0 )
            break;
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC + u_radius * step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC - u_radius * step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
    }
    gaussCol.rgb = clamp( gaussCol.rgb / gaussCol.w, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( gaussCol.rgb, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<div>
<form id="gui" name="inputs">
<table>
<tr> <td> <font color= #CCF>radius</font> </td> 
        <td> <input type="range" id="radius" min="1" max="1000" value="350" onchange="changeEventHandler(event);"/></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <font color= #CCF>blur</font> </td> 
        <td> <input type="range" id="sigma" min="1" max="100" value="5" onchange="changeEventHandler(event);"/></td> </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;"></canvas>
```