# How to add alpha value in blur shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, gaussianblur

In the following blur shader currently the output image has alpha value of 1.0 , but  i want the alpha to be dependent on the blur of the image.

The shader code has been taken from the following question.

[OpenGL es 2.0 Gaussian blur on triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779142/opengl-es-2-0-gaussian-blur-on-triangle)

The portion of image which does not show the blur should have alpha value of 0.

I have tried many options but i really dont understand how can we add the alpha values to the final image.

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 pos;

// texture sampler
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2      u_textureSize;
uniform float     u_sigma;
uniform float     u_radius;
uniform vec2      u_dir;

float CalcGauss( float x, float sigma)
{
   if( sigma <= 0.0 )
    return 0.0;
return exp( -(x * x) / ( 2.0 * sigma)) / ( 2.0 * 3.14157 * sigma);

}

void main()
{
    vec2 texC     = pos.st * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec4 texCol   = texture2D( u_texture, texC );
    vec4 gaussCol = vec4( texCol.rgb, 1.0 );
    vec2 step     = u_dir / u_textureSize;
    float weight;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 16; ++ i )
    {
        weight = CalcGauss( float(i) / 16.0, u_sigma * 0.5 );
        if ( weight < 1.0/255.0 )
            break;
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC + u_radius * step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC - u_radius * step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
    }
    
   gaussCol.rgb = clamp( gaussCol.rgb / gaussCol.w, 0.0, 1.0 );
   FragColor = vec4( gaussCol.rgb , 1.0 );

}
```

i have changed the shader this is the new code.

```
void main()
{
    vec2 texC     = pos.st * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec4 texCol   = texture2D( u_texture, texC );
    vec4 gaussCol = vec4(texCol);
    vec2 step     = u_dir / u_textureSize;
    float weight;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 64; ++ i )
    {
        weight = CalcGauss( float(i) / 64, u_sigma * 0.5 );
        if ( weight < 1.0 / 255.0 )
            break;
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC + u_radius * step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight ,  weight);
        texCol    = texture2D( u_texture, texC - u_radius * step * float(i) );
        gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight ,  weight);
    }
    
    gaussCol.rgba = clamp(gaussCol.rgba, 0.0, 1.0);  
    FragColor =   vec4(gaussCol.rgb , gaussCol.a);

}
```

The following image is the new result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have copied the shader form a [WebGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/). WebGL by default uses [premultiplied alpha](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html), but your desktop application does not. See [Straight versus premultiplied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Straight_versus_premultiplied).  In compare to the WebGL shader you have to skip the division of the weighted sum of the color channels by the weighted sum of the alpha channel:

<s>`gaussCol.rgb = clamp( gaussCol.rgb / gaussCol.w, 0.0, 1.0 );`</s>

```c
gaussCol.rgb = clamp(gaussCol.rgb, 0.0, 1.0);
```

---

If the back ground is cleared with an alpha channel of 0.0 (e.g. `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, which is default, then you can "blur" the alpha channel, too.

Initialize `gaussCol` with all the 4 channels of the texture:

```c
vec4 gaussCol = texCol.rgba;
```

Take into account the final alpha channel:

```c
gaussCol.rgba = clamp(gaussCol.rgba, 0.0, 1.0);
FragColor = gaussCol;
```

respectively

```c
FragColor = clamp(gaussCol, 0.0, 1.0);
```

---

If you want that the alpha channel is either 0 or 1, then you have to set the channel dependent on the alpha value:

```c
gaussCol = clamp(gaussCol, 0.0, 1.0);
FragColor = vec4(gaussCol.rgb, gaussCol > 0.001 ? 1.0 : 0.0);
```

Comment: i have made the changes but now the blur effect is gone.

Comment: if i render alpha only FragColor = vec4(gaussCol.a, gaussCol.a , gaussCol.a, gaussCol.a );

Comment: the whole screen turns white.

Comment: when i use this vec4(gaussCol.rgb , gaussCol.r);

Comment: i am able to see the background  , when i use gaussCol.a the image becomes opaque.

Comment: i feel as if alpha is always not becoming transparent.

Comment: @Summit `vec4 gaussCol = vec4(texCol.rgb, 1.0);` -> `vec4 gaussCol = texCol.rgba`